# How to use Azure Authentication in general?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I have an app that has Identity Server 4, I am trying to set up logins in Azure, so the user tries to login, gets redirected to Azure, then back to my app. Using open id connect.

This is my error:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
  "title": "IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsyncInternal(AuthenticationProperties properties)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)\n   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)",
  "traceId": "00-de68e90101e08747bb21693393700b26-3f4d40290df44049-00"
}
```

My code:

```
        private void AddAuth(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Azure", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientId = "clientId";
    options.Authority = "myauth";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";

    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page 
        // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
        if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
        {
            // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
            context.Response.Redirect("/Session/ResetPassword");
        }
        else if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("access_denied"))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Failure.Message));
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

            services.AddAuthorization();
        }
```

Please note that myauth is an URL

I am trying to follow this example https://www.domstamand.com/connecting-azure-ad-and-azure-ad-b2c-to-identityserver4/ but I don't get why in the failures exactly says System.String instead of its value, so apparently I am not passing properly the values.

Comment: Is this authority correct? `options.Authority = "myauth";` It should be a URL that the OpenID Connect handler can use to get the configuration metadata. It will do a concatenation to get the config URL like this: `authority + "/.well-known/openid-configuration`. For example, if I wanted to configure multi-tenant Azure AD auth, I'd set the authority to `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0"`, so that the handler can get the config from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration. You can do the same thing to test if your config is correct.

Comment: myauth is an url, if I click on there, adding the extra string, it works

Comment: Okay, in that case it could be that the URL is not reachable from the server somehow. Is there a proxy or firewall that could block the request?